# How to import csv file to mongodb in pyspark (or python)?

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, pymongo

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
my_spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("myApp") \
     .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testtt.coll") \
     .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testtt.coll") \
     .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv(path = "file:///home/user/Desktop/testtt.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)


df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("database","testtt").option("collection", "coll").save()
```

Comment: You will need to clarify what your actual question / isses is.

Comment: I did this code and I have error, what is the right code to import csv file to mongodb in python

Comment: do you use pymongo?

Comment: yes, but there are nothing to help!

Comment: Why do you need your own CSV importer? Why not use `mongoimport` which has a native CSV importing support?

Comment: Good question, because I'm already in pyspark not need to connect the file then open it ( my files are Zip files, so I'm open it in pyspark then process it in mongodb), my main problem with save the file in mongodb